# Django 1.6 Return HttpResponseNotFound() from a recursive function

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to make  return HttpResponseNotFound() return recursively so it can be used as intended? The reason I ask is because I would like to re-use get_thread_and_user() and keep the code DRY as possible.

```
def get_thread_and_user(request, thread_id):
    try:
        thread_id=777
        thread = ThreadVault.objects.get(thread_id=thread_id)
        user = Employee.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    #TODO: Fix to broad exception
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound(
            '<h1>Oh snap! There\'s a database error!</h1>')
    return thread, user

def assign_thread(request, thread_id):
    thread, user = get_thread_and_user(request, thread_id)

    if thread.assigned_user is None:
        try:
            thread.assigned_user = user
            thread.last_modified_by = user
            thread.save()
         except:
            return HttpResponseNotFound(
                '<h1>Oh snap! There\'s a database error!</h1>')
    else:
        return render_to_response('bot_data/assign_confirm.html',
                {'user' : user})
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://10.1.55.78:8000/unanswered")
```

Comment: I can't figure out what do you mean by recursively in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than returning that HttpResponse, you should instead raise the specific Http404 exception, which will bubble up to the middleware and return the 404 message.

Also, you should *never* catch a bare except. Always only catch the exceptions that you are expecting.

```
except ThreadVault.DoesNotExist, Employee.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404(
        '<h1>Oh snap! There\'s a database error!</h1>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Return the result of `get_thread_and_user`

```
def get_thread_and_user(request, thread_id):
    return HTTPResponseNotFound("Error  TIME!")

def assign_thread(request, thread_id):
     return get_thread_and_user(request, thread_id)
```

You can also `raise` it as an exception. This will jump out of the whole view flow. As long as you don't `except` it will bubble into the framework and return the correct code to the user.